# ASP.NET WebControls are not appearing in my VS 2008 toolbox

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-controls

It's been a while since I've created a new ASP.NET web application. (I've been doing ASP.NET MVC for the last 9 months, and hadn't done an ASP.NET site for about a year before that.) Now I've created a new regular ASP.NET app and when I look at the Default.aspx file, Visual Studio is only displaying the HTML tab in the Toolbox. I don't have the WebControls or the data access controls. (I don't even remember what other tabs I should be seeing.)

When I try to add a web control manually like this,

```
<asp:Label id="LabelTest" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

I get a green squiggly and the tool tip says `Unrecognized namespace 'asp'.`

What do I need to do to get the Web Controls in my toolbox and also get the namespace to be recognized?

I've got this line in my page load event:

```
LabelTest.Text = "testing"
```

My app compiles and runs as expected -- the label displays `testing`.

So, I could word around it, but this will just make designing the forms more difficult.

**Update:** I've tried all 3 of the suggestions posted as answers so far and nothing has helped. Now I'm seeing a different error in addition to what I was getting before. In the designer I now see this:

> Error Creating Control - LabelTest
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Authoring' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried repairing the Visual Studio installation?

Pops-in the disc and select "Repair"?

If that doesn't work, then I think you should just re-install Visual Studio... It seems like a plugins/add-on corrupted the toolbox

Comment: Well, something serious must be wrong with my machine because when I try that I get "A problem has been encountered while loading the setup components. Canceling setup." :(

Comment: I double clicked on Visual Studio 2008 in Programs and Features and it launched the repair, which is running now...

Comment: Nope, that still didn't help.

Comment: @Dennis Palmer I think you should just re-install Visual Studio... It seems like you have some plugins/addons that corrupts the toolbox

Comment: Accepted answer for re-install comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

1. `removing and then re-adding` the assembly references and then
2. `rebuilding` the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "Reset Toolbox" command?

[reset toolbox http://chakrit.net/files/stackoverflow/so_reset_toolbox.png](http://chakrit.net/files/stackoverflow/so_reset_toolbox.png)

...